# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') after updating nodejs

Tags: node.js

I updated Nodejs to 16.17.1 and got this error in the browser when running my react website:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

I rolled back my nodejs version back to 16.17.0 and still have the same issue. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `node_modules` directory and rebuild nodejs with `yarn install`